# How can I give access to my plugin sections in admin?

Tags: plugin-development

This is my first plugin using roles and capabilities. How can I give the "subscriber" users access to my plugin in the WP admin, or make a menu for just subscribers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the parts you want a subscriber to see by wrapping the code with:

```
if ( current_user_can( 'read' ) ){
    // the code you want the subscriber to see
}
```

You can checkout the role and capabilities here https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Subscriber

Comment: Super, but i fixed changing the manage_options to "read", and after that some logic to show/hide things. Thanks!